# What are potential risks of setting VARCHAR(8000)

Tags: sql, sql-injection, varchar

I'm building a webapplication. Users can insert messages into the database. I use a size of 8000.

My security measures:

- the data is plain text or
- HTML with only a strict subset is allowed (checked with an XSS algorithm)
- entered via a prepared statement

I'm wondering if such a large size has other (security) risks or performance issues I should be aware of?

Comment: The largest size is `varchar(max)`.  Why not use that?

Comment: Why would there be issues? Databases can hold an enormous amount of data, if there were risks at using too much, it would be a pretty crappy db.

Comment: What database are you using? Most have a field for this kind of thing, like the text type in Postgres or the CLOB in Oracle. Make sure that your database supports a VARCHAR as big as 8000. For example, in Oracle, a VARCHAR can not exceed 4000 bytes.

Comment: The size of the data isn't a risk. Performance shouldn't be that bad either, although for large messages you may use `text` fields instead of `varchar`. They are stored in a different way (in a separate space).

Comment: @JimArcher, either MSSQL or MySQL.

Comment: @Mouser okay so lookup the storage requirements, this is more an issue of efficiency and perhaps indexing based on the database you choose. There are no security issues related to the field type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there are no security issues particular to using a large buffer. As you seem to have noted your two key vulnerability are:
1. people inserting malicious scripts into the HTML
2. sql injection.

Filtering out to only keep benign tags helps you with the first issue and using the prepared statement should protect you from sql-injection which is the most common vulnerability.